# Combining Hash of String and Hash of Long

Tags: java

I have the following java class:

```
public class Person{
   String name;  //a unique name
   Long DoB;     //a unique time
   .
   .
   .
   @Override
   public int hashCode(){
     return name.hashCode() + DoB.hashCode();
   }

}
```

Is my hashCode method correct (i.e. would it return a unique number of all combinations.

I have a feeling I'm missing something here.

Comment: The `equals` override. You might want to multiply the long by something odd, e.g., 31.

Comment: no, it won't be. `hash(a) + hash(b) != hash(a+b)`. while not exactly easy to do, someone could probably find a completely different SINGLE string that hashes to the same value as your combined hash(a)+hash(b).

Comment: @DaveNewton I have the equal override too. should I add it to the question?

Comment: @nafas No, it's more of a "make sure you do this right" comment. I might add that you have it, though, to avoid the inevitable pile-on.

Comment: It can not be unique (there are more `Long`s in `DoS` alone than there are possible hashes), and it does not have to be. The question should be: is it unique _enough_?

Comment: I recommend not reinventing the wheel.  Use the apache commons lang hashCodeBuilder (https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.1/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might also want to use something more fluent and more NPE-bulletproof like [Google Guava](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Objects.html):

```
@Override
public int hashCode(){
    return Objects.hashCode(name, DoB);
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if ( this == o ) {
        return true;
    }
    if ( o == null || o.getClass() != Person.class ) {
        return false;
    }
    final Person that = (Person) o;
    return Objects.equal(name, that.name) && Objects.equal(DoB, that.DoB);
}
```

---

Edit:

IntelliJ IDEA and Eclipse can generate more efficient `hashCode()` and `equals()`.

Comment: **+1** I didn't show my equals method, its almost same as yours Except that I don't checking if o is null.

Answer (score 3):

You could let `java.util.Arrays` do it for you:

```
return Arrays.hashCode(new Object[]{ name, DoB });
```

Answer (score 1):

Aside for the obvious, which is, you might want to implement the `equals` method as well...

- Summing two hash codes has the very small risk of overflowing `int`
- The sum itself seems like a bit of a weak methodology to provide unique hash codes. I would instead try some bitwise manipulation and use a seed.

Answer (score 0):

usually a hashcode is build like so:

```
   @Override
   public int hashCode(){
     return name.hashCode() ^ DoB.hashCode();
   }
```

but the important thing to remember when doing a hashcode method is the use of it. the use of hashcode method is to put different object in different buckets in a hashtable or other collection using hashcode. as such, it's impotent to have a method that gives different answers to different objects at a low run time but doesn't have to be different for every item, though it's better that way.

> This hash is used by other code when storing or manipulating the
>   instance – the values are intended to be evenly distributed for varied
>   inputs in order to use in clustering. This property is important to
>   the performance of hash tables and other data structures that store
>   objects in groups ("buckets") based on their computed hash values

and

> The general contract for overridden implementations of this method is
>   that they behave in a way consistent with the same object's equals()
>   method: that a given object must consistently report the same hash
>   value (unless it is changed so that the new version is no longer
>   considered "equal" to the old), and that two objects which equals()
>   says are equal must report the same hash value.

Answer (score 0):

See Bloch's Effective Java #9.

But you should start with an initial value (so that subsequent zero values are significant), and combine the fields that apply to the result along with a multiplier so that order is significant (so that similar classes will have much different hashes.)

Also, you will have to treat things like long fields and Strings a little different. e.g., for longs:

```
(int) (field ^ (field>>>32))
```

So, this means something like:

```
@Override public int hashCode() {
   int result = 17;
   result += name.hashCode() == null ? 0 : name.hashCode();
   result = 31 * result + (int) (DoB ^ (DoB >>> 32));
   return result;
}
```

31 is slightly magic, but odd primes can make it easier for the compiler to optimize the math to shift-subtraction. (Or you can do the shift-subtraction yourself, but why not let the compiler do it.)

Answer (score 0):

Your hash code implementation is fine and correct.  It could be better if you follow any of the suggestions other people have made, but it satisfies the contract for `hashCode`, and collisions aren't particularly likely, though they could be made less likely.